# Open source wiki in Java (similar to Foswiki)

Tags: open-source, java, wiki

The features of [Foswiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foswiki) are really very very good. However I am looking for a similar wiki built in Java so that we will have portability, cross-platform support, etc.

Do we have any good open source wiki developed in Java which has lots of features?

Comment: Since this Is web application which can be deployed on Windows, MacOS and Linux, how more cross platform are you looking for?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Basiclally java, so that if there are any issues, we could able to fix it ourself or understand the issue better than other prog languages

Comment: If that's reason, why don't you edit the question because "portability, cross-platform support" is not the reason.

Comment: @EricShain I think the author meant the *wiki server* is portable across platforms so they could deploy to any kind of host computer. Portable for the sysadmin rather than the end-user.

Comment: @BasilBourque Which FosWiki is. Nothing about Java makes it more portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## XWiki

[image]

[This comparison page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software) lists [XWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xwiki) as a [Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))-based wiki having as its predecessor [TWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWiki), from which your mentioned [FosWiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foswiki) was forked.

> XWiki is a free wiki software platform written in Java with a design emphasis on extensibility. XWiki is an enterprise wiki. It includes [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editing, [OpenDocument](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) based document import/export, semantic annotations and tagging, and advanced permissions management.